# How can I call a method (in main Activity) from push service?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem when I receive a push notification, I use 2 devices in my app, both are in the main activity, when one of them is used to send a message (using GCM) the other is waiting. Then the second device receives the push notification (using GCMIntentService.class) and it should call a method that is in the main activity, but it doesn't work... It crashes...

Here is the code of GCMIntentService: (The methods which are not written of GCMIntentService work fine)

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    int enprimerplano;
    String usuariocontrario, usuario, regId;
    String partida;
     public GCMIntentService(){

      super("681111424695");
     }

     @Override
     protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
      Log.d("GCM", "Error: " + errorId);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String msg = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
         Log.d("GCM", "Mensaje: " + msg);
             notificarMensaje(context, msg);
     }
 private void notificarMensaje(Context context, String msg)
     {
        MultijugadorNormal m = new MultijugadorNormal();
        m.Empezar();
        m.NoEmpezarHasta();
     }
```

Empezar() and NoEmpezarHasta() are methods of Main Activity

Comment: Can you post some more information such as a minimal working version of your code?

Comment: Please add some code snippet and a crash log.

Comment: Ok! I am going to put the code!

Comment: I have solved it!! I have used a BroadCastReceiver in Main Activity

Comment: Please, provide it as answer and mark it as solution in order to close the question.